# Flatten xml hierarchy using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, hierarchy, flatten

I would like to convert a nested xml to flatten xml using XSLT.

Incoming xml Structure would be similar but the node names would change for the incoming xmls, so would like to handle in dynamically

Sample input

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<queryResponse>
  <Account>
    <Id>0010</Id>
    <Name>AA</Name>
    <RecordTypeId>0122/RecordTypeId>
    <RecordType>
      <Id>012</Id>
      <DeveloperName>Legal_Associate</DeveloperName>
    </RecordType>
  </Account>
  <Account>
    <Id>0011</Id>
    <Name>BB</Name>
    <RecordTypeId>0123</RecordTypeId>
    <RecordType>
      <Id>013</Id>
      <DeveloperName>Legal_Associate</DeveloperName>
    </RecordType>
  </Account>
 </queryResponse>
```

Expected Output

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<queryResponse>
  <Account>
    <Id>0010</Id>
    <Name>AA</Name>
    <RecordTypeId>0122</RecordTypeId>
    <RecordType.Id>012</RecordType.Id>
  <RecordType.DeveloperName>Legal_Associate</RecordType.DeveloperName>
  </Account>
  <Account>
    <Id>0011</Id>
    <Name>BB</Name>
    <RecordTypeId>0123<RecordTypeId>
    <RecordType.Id>013</RecordType.Id>    <RecordType.DeveloperName>Legal_Associate</RecordType.DeveloperName>
    </Account>
    </queryResponse>
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: I'm able to achieve it for fixed node names, but how it can be handled for dynamic node names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While posting the question you should post the tried code as well hense we can tell you the updation.

Here is the code which you can achive your answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="RecordType">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:element name="{concat(name(..),'.',name())}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: you can see the transformation here too: http://xsltransform.net/jxN8NpY

Comment: Thanks a lot Amrendra , Going forth will update the code. I'm able to acheive this , but is there way i could do it for all Nodes which has child nodes. Rather putting <xsl:template match="RecordType"> , it should be taking node which has childs

Comment: <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:element name="{concat(name(..),'.',name())}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>